# My preventDefault is not working when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, preventdefault

I am currently working to learn different Javascript features. I am working with preventDefault. I was attempting to practice on the website I am making, but it is still refreshing the page. What am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```js
formSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form role="form">
  <label for="fname" class="labelI">First Name:</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="fName" id="fname" required> <br>
  <label for="lName" class="labelI"></label>Last Name:</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" required> <br>
  <label for="emailA" class="labelI"></label>Email Address:</label> <br>
  <input type="email" name="Email" id="emailA" required><br>
  <label for="password" class="labelI"></label>Password</label> <br>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="5" maxlength="12"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="but" id="formSubmit">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="but">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Your DOM might not be read and ready. Always place non `defer` `<script>` tags right before the **closing** `</body>` tag.
- Try not to use IDs as immediate `window` properties for your ID selectors. Even if this might work for historical reasons, always create a variable reference to your  DOM elements using [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) Methods
- Don't use `"click"` Event when you actually want to listen to a `"submit"` event on the FORM itself. Such will also allow the browser to ignite the input-*type* attributes like `required` `pattern` etc.

```html
<body>
    <form role="form" id="myForm">
        <label for="fname" class="labelI">First Name:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="fName" id="fname" required> <br>
        <label for="lName" class="labelI"></label>Last Name:</label> <br>
        <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" required> <br>
        <label for="emailA" class="labelI"></label>Email Address:</label> <br>
        <input type="email" name="Email" id="emailA" required><br>
        <label for="password" class="labelI"></label>Password</label> <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="5" maxlength="12"> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="but" id="formSubmit">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="but">
    </form>

    <!-- Place all your <script>s right BEFORE the closing BODY tag -->
    <script>
        const EL_myForm = document.querySelector("#myForm");
        EL_myForm.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default browser SUBMIT action
            console.log("Form not submitted yet. Do your JS magic here!");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

formSubmit is not a variable. You must grab a reference to an element.

```
document.getElementById('formSubmit').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to select button with id `formSubmit`.

```
var sel = document.getElementById("formSubmit");
sel.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

You cant add event listener directly to id 'formSubmit'

Comment: The last statement is incorrect. For historic reasons, element IDs are available as global variables referencing the element unless overridden by a same named declared variable. So `formSubmit.addEventListener(...)` works provided it's run when the *formSubmit* element exists.

Comment: @RobG but we can not add event listener directly to id or class variables, right? To select DOM elements we are using these.

Comment: You *can*, but it's a bad idea. ID's as global variables was introduced in a very early version of IE, it was considered a terrible idea but other browsers copied it for compatibility reasons. Now it seems it's with us forever because no one wants to "break the web". :-)

Comment: @RobG but then why it was not working though?

Comment: Perhaps because the code was running before the element exists in the page. Otherwise, it "works". :-)

Answer (score -1):

add an id to your form let say id="form1" and add this code:

```
var myform = document.getElementById("form1"); myfom.addEventListener('submit',function(e){e.preventDefault();});

<form role="form" id="form1">
 <label for="fname" class="labelI">First Name:</label> <br>
 <input type="text" name="fName" id="fname" required> <br>
 <label for="lName" class="labelI"></label>Last Name:</label> <br>
 <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" required> <br>
 <label for="emailA" class="labelI"></label>Email Address:</label> <br>
 <input type="email" name="Email" id="emailA" required><br>
 <label for="password" class="labelI"></label>Password</label> <br>
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="5" 
  maxlength="12"> <br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="but" id="formSubmit">
 <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="but">
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add a class "form" to your form element as a reference element. **You should also not that i have used es6 syntax.**

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<form class="form" role="form">
  <label for="fname" class="labelI">First Name:</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="fName" id="fname" required> <br>
  <label for="lName" class="labelI"></label>Last Name:</label> <br>
  <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" required> <br>
  <label for="emailA" class="labelI"></label>Email Address:</label> <br>
  <input type="email" name="Email" id="emailA" required><br>
  <label for="password" class="labelI"></label>Password</label> <br>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" minlength="5" maxlength="12"> <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="but" id="formSubmit">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="but">
</form>
```